# Using nvm for running a single command with different node version

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have node 8 required for my project, but I need to use node 10 for running one of my build command. Is it good to use nvm for running single command with different node version or shall I upgrade my project with higher node version?

Comment: upgrade to higher version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jaysurya , But Is it unsafe to use nvm for running single command with different node version? I think it would be easy rather than updating the whole project to new node version.

Comment: I dont think its unsafe, it is inconvenient. Node 10 doesnot have any notable or breaking changes from node 8, only enhancements. So upgrading would require probably no changes in the project.